# Fetch Records Based On Count And Within Certain Time Interval

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, timestamp

I have a table `LOGIN_DETAILS` in Oracle 11g, where details of user after each login are kept. I want to fetch the name of the user who has done more than 5 logins in any 30 minutes of interval.

**Example:**

Consider Following Records:

[image]

In above records MACK has done 6 logins within 07-08-17 05:10:17 and 07-08-17 05:40:17 that is within 30 minutes of interval.
So the query should return the name 'MACK' as output.

> **Note**: 30 minutes interval is not pre-defined, that is it is not defined from were 30 minutes interval should start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`.  The following gets the last row when there are 5 within 30 minutes:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(login_timestamp, 4) over (partition by unique_code order by login_timestamp) as prev_lt
      from t
     ) t
where login_timestamp < prev_lt + interval '30' minute;
```

Note that the `lag()` goes back 4 records, because the current record is the fifth.

Answer (score 1):

something like that

```
with t as (
            select 'Mack' Name, sysdate-0.05 tt from dual
            union all
            select 'Mack' Name, sysdate-0.03 from dual
            union all
            select 'Mack' Name, sysdate-0.04 from dual
            union all
            select 'Angel' Name, sysdate-0.005 from dual            
           )
select name, min(tt), max(tt), (max(tt) - min(tt)) * 24 * 60, count(*)
from t
group by name
having count(*) > 2 -- qnt of logins
    and (max(tt) - min(tt)) * 24 * 60 > 20 -- interval 20 min
```